# How to intercept ntlm authentication based application?

Tags: authentication, burp-suite, ntlm

There is an internal application which authenticates based on windows credentials (NTLM Authentication). It is not intercepting while in proxy with Burp Suite and is stuck in login pop-up even after providing correct credentials. Upon removing the proxy, the application works fine.

Is there any way by which we can intercept the application?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Burp's Platform Authentication settings let you configure Burp to automatically carry out platform authentication to destination web servers. Different authentication types and credentials can be configured for individual hosts.

- https://support.portswigger.net/customer/portal/articles/2927576-configuring-ntlm-with-burp-suite